# Merge two non system partitions but with software installed

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

In my pc build I have two disk drives, an ssd and an hdd. My hdd is split into two partitions, both of which contain data. One contains mostly files and the other contains installed software and files. Windows and is installed on the SSD. I am aware that merging the Windows partition with another might create some issues and break windows (bootloader, system files etc). Would merging the two partitions that exist on the hdd cause any problems?

Comment: No; but if you installed the software you should change the drive letter to the same, but merging involves the deletion of one partition and extending the other

Comment: @Ramhound is technically right, but the way he describes it sounds destructive.  So, I would just add that software does exist which can do this without destroying the files you have on the filesystem.  (For such software to work, it needs to know details about whatever kind of filesystem you are using.)  Most people consider the maneuver to be rather risky, so people are especially recommended to have a *conveniently available* back up their data before doing this (even more than the general recommendation to always have data be backed up)

Comment: @TOOGAM So probably I should backup. Ok. But should I backup both partitions?

Comment: Yes. If something does go wrong, it can affect either partition, or even both. This caution was strongly stressed when some of the first partition-modifying software (FIPS) first came out (maybe mid-1990s).  Reliability has increased tremendously since then, but last I checked, many experts were still uneasy about such processes if backups weren't readily available. So, the concept of "*reliability*" demands you can restore the data somehow.  For this type of process, people often make another backup for *convenience* (if they have the resources, like an available device with free space).

Comment: @TOOGAM Merge all the comments in an answer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For such software to work, it needs to know details about whatever kind of filesystem you are using.) Most people consider the maneuver to be rather risky, so people are especially recommended to have a conveniently available back up their data before doing this (even more than the general recommendation to always have data be backed up).

Do back up any important data from both partitions that will be merged, before starting the merge.  If something does go wrong, it can affect either partition, or even both. This caution was strongly stressed when some of the first partition-modifying software (FIPS) first came out (maybe mid-1990s). Reliability has increased tremendously since then, but last I checked, many experts were still uneasy about such processes if backups weren't readily available. So, the concept of "reliability" demands you can restore the data somehow. For this type of process, people often make another backup for convenience (if they have the resources, like an available device with free space).

Answer (score 1):

To 'merge' two partitions I have previously applied this algorithm, but with a windows 7 installation. You shouldn't try this without a backup.

1. Boot into Windows
2. Move as many files as possible from the second to the first partition.
3. Defrag, defrag, defrag the second drive to move files away from the partition end and more to the beginning of it.
4. Reboot using an ubuntu live cd.
5. Using parted, reduce the size of the second partition as much as possible.
6. Move the second partition to the end of the disk.
7. Enlarge the first partition as much as possible.

Repeat until there are no more files on the second partition, then delete it using parted and resize the first one to take all space.